# Saving uploaded images outside a docker container in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a Spring boot application running on a docker container, file path for saving images is configured in the application.properties file.
I was trying to save uploaded images outside the container. Following is my configurations for the same.

In application.properties

```
location.image.products-location = /home/uploads/images
```

Docker file

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/products-app-0.1.jar
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:latest
        networks:
            - products-net
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: products
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        volumes:
            - products-mysql_v:/var/lib/mysql
            - /home/uploads/images/:/opt/app/images/

    products-app:
        image: products-app-0.1
        container_name: products-app
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 8001:8001
        networks:
            - products-net
        depends_on:
          - mysql
networks:
    products-net:
volumes:
    products-mysql_v:
```

I'm always getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to save the image. Can anyone help me how to configure the Docker volume for writing and reading a file outside a container in a Spring based application.

Comment: Hi, how did you solve it?

Comment: Can you try adding `mysql` under volumes at the last instead of `products-mysql_v:`